# Memory management in Linked Lists C

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list, malloc

I am trying to implement a linked list data structure that represents a folder tree.

The structures below:

```
typedef struct SRC_ERROR SRC_ERROR;
struct SRC_ERROR {
    int error_code;
    char *error;
};

typedef struct SRC_FILE SRC_FILE;
struct SRC_FILE {
    char *entry;
    char md5[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
};

typedef struct SRC SRC; //Source file tree with md5 entry char for source verification.
struct SRC {
    SRC_ERROR error;
    char *name;
    char *full_path;
    SRC_FILE **entries;
    SRC *next_dir;
};
```

The idea was that each directory will be stored in `SRC` the `SRC_FILE` is to be used as an array to store the filename and MD5 hash for each file.

The `scan_source()` below populates the structures.

```
SRC *scan_source(char *source_path) {
    SRC *source = malloc(sizeof(SRC));
    source->error.error_code = OK;
    int count = 0;
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;

    if (!(dir = opendir(source_path))) {
        source->error.error_code = ERROR;
        source->error.error = "Unable to open source directory.\n";
        return source;
    }

    source->entries = (SRC_FILE **)malloc(sizeof(SRC_FILE *) * count);

    if (source->entries == NULL) {
        source->error.error_code = ERROR;
        source->error.error = "Unable to allocate memory to file entry tree\n";
    }

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            char path[PATH_MAX];

            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
                continue;

            snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/%s", source_path, entry->d_name);
            printf("[%s] - %s\n", entry->d_name, path);

            //add new node
            source = add_dir(source, insert_dir_node(entry->d_name, path));

            scan_source(path);
        } else
        if (entry->d_type == DT_REG) {
            printf("[FILE] - %s\n", entry->d_name);
            source->entries[count]->entry = entry->d_name; //SEGFAULT HERE
            count++;
            source->entries = realloc(source->entries, sizeof(SRC_FILE *) * (count));
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
    return source;
}
```

I am having issues with memory management. I am getting intermittent seg faults when the directory is structured in certain ways.

I have marked the line that the debugger has flagged

```
source->entries[count]->entry = entry->d_name; //SEGFAULT HERE
```

I thought that I allocated memory for each structure but maybe I have not done this correctly or there is an underlying problem with the data structure entirely?

For Example:

```
test> tree
.
└── Text

0 directories, 1 file
```

This causes a seg fault. Whereas, this does not:

```
/test> tree
.
├── another sample
│   └── Text
└── sample folder

2 directories, 1 file
```

Additional functions that are used:

```
SRC *add_dir(SRC *file_tree, SRC *new_dir) {
    new_dir->next_dir = file_tree;
    return new_dir;
}

SRC *insert_dir_node(char *name, char *full_path) {
    SRC *next_dir;
    next_dir = (SRC *)emalloc(sizeof(SRC));
    next_dir->name = name;
    next_dir->full_path = full_path;
    next_dir->next_dir = NULL;
    return next_dir;
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with `c++`?

Comment: similar languages, both with some kind of manual memory management features. Is it an issue?

Comment: @cigien Maybe because it's the sort of code that would be so much simpler if it was written in C++.

Comment: @user4581301 Is it ok for me to just remove the tag in this case? I'm unsure about that.

Comment: @cigien Unless you think the OP is actually looking for a C++ solution. I don't think they are.

Comment: @hdcdigi They are not really very similar. This code could look quite different in c++.

Comment: @hdcdigi This will likely compile in C++ and make a valid C++, program, but you generally write a very different-looking linked list in C++. When you tag both languages you'll get a bunch of answers that lead in very different directions and result in more confusion than it's worth.

Comment: @hdcdigi The problem is that the way you would approach this problem in C and C++ are radically different. The code you've written might be perfectly good C (bugs notwithstanding) but it's really awful C++.

Comment: Understood. Also thought that people who know c++ well may have some c knowledge too.

Comment: Indeed they do, but you run the risk of getting C++ answers and commentary like the seemingly obligatory, "Why aren't you using `std::list`?" The tighter you focus a question, the better the results. The C++ folk who want to answer C and C++ questions will monitor the C tag as well.

Comment: You set count to 0 and then, used malloc with size 0 bytes. This is implementation dependent and may or may not result in NULL pointer. I'm guessing this could cause some errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started looking at the code, and the first issue I see is that you're storing pointers returned by a `readdir()` call - you should copy the data contained therein instead.

Change

```
source = add_dir(source, insert_dir_node(entry->d_name, path));
```

to

```
source = add_dir(source, insert_dir_node(strdup(entry->d_name), path));
```

The reason you're seeing segmentation faults is that you always write after the end of the `source->entries` array.

You initially create a 0-size array:

```
    int count = 0;
/* ... */
    source->entries = (SRC_FILE **) malloc(sizeof(SRC_FILE*) * count);
```

Then set its 1st (indexed by 0) element:

```
            source->entries[count]->entry = entry->d_name; //SEGFAULT HERE
            count++;
            source->entries = realloc(source->entries, sizeof(SRC_FILE*)*(count));
```

Then you expand the array to 1 element, then write to the second index, and so on.

You can either fix the logic (allocate space for `count+1` elements always, because you want to have room not only for the existing ones but also for the next one), or, which in this case may be more efficient, switch to a linked list structure here as well.

The next problem is that you're only allocating pointers to SRC_FILE, not SRC_FILE structures - you should change the definition to:

```
struct SRC {
    SRC_ERROR error;
    char *name;
    char *full_path;
    SRC_FILE *entries;
    SRC *next_dir;
};
```

And the initialization to

```
source->entries = (SRC_FILE *) malloc(sizeof(SRC_FILE) * (count + 1));
```

Then the critical part to

```
source->entries[count].entry = strdup(entry->d_name);
count++;
source->entries = realloc(source->entries, sizeof(SRC_FILE) * (count + 1));
```

There's one more thing to attend to: `insert_dir_node` creates a new SRC struct, which will need to have a freshly initialized entries member:

```
next_dir->count = 0;
next_dir->entries = (SRC_FILE *)malloc(sizeof(SRC_FILE) * (1));
```

- and, since we have now separate `entries` we need to have a `count` for each of them, so move this variable into the struct as well.

Fixing all of these provided me with an error-free program.

Comment: Thanks this helped. It runs fully on a tree of empty folders. However as soon as a file is placed in the tree. I get another seg fault. Also I can't figure out what the issue is with the path variable. I think that this maybe causing some problems. It appears that the list does not update the full path correctly. See output from the main loop of the `readdir()` vs output from the list. ```[sample] - test/sample
[sub_test] - test/sub_test
[subsample] - test/sub_test/subsample

NAME: sub_test - PATH: test/sub_test
NAME: sample - PATH: test/sub_test
NAME: (null) - PATH: (null)```

Comment: Not sure of best practice to reply to your answer? Comments seem limited, do I update my main question? Maybe i need to go back and revise my memory allocation and data structures, before I continue with this project.

Comment: I have found the remaining problems, edited the answer. And yes it would be best if you re-thought how you want to approach storing the data - the current version works, but a cleaner approach could be better in terms of peformance and simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

The subject is *Memory management in linked lists*. Indeed this is a major issue in C program because there is no automatic memory management. You must decide and specify how each object pointed to by a pointer in your structures is handled from a memory management standpoint. Is the pointer **the** reference for the object life time or is the lifetime handled somewhere else and the pointer just an access point.

Let's analyse your object definitions:

```
typedef struct SRC_ERROR SRC_ERROR;
struct SRC_ERROR {
    int error_code;
    char *error;
};
```

`SRC_ERROR` is just a way to package an error description. If the `error` member always stores a pointer to a string literal, it should be defined as `const char *`. Conversely, if in some cases you allocate a string with information specific to the actual error, such as `"error allocating 1023 objects\n"`, then you either need an indicator specifying the `error` points to allocated memory that should be freed after use or you should always allocate memory for the error message and always free this memory when discarding the `SRC_ERROR` object.

```
typedef struct SRC_FILE SRC_FILE;
struct SRC_FILE {
    char *entry;
    char md5[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
};
```

`entry` should point to allocated memory and this memory should be freed when discarding the `SRC_FILE` object.

```
typedef struct SRC SRC; //Source file tree with md5 entry char for source verification.
struct SRC {
    SRC_ERROR error;
    char *name;
    char *full_path;
    SRC_FILE **entries;
    SRC *next_dir;
};
```

- `name` and `full_path` should point to allocated memory and should be freed when discarding the `SRC` object.
- `next_dir` points to another `SRC` object, which should be allocated and freed consistently.
- `entries` points to an allocated array, each element of which points to an allocated object. You need a way to tell the number of elements in this array. You could maintain a `NULL` pointer at the end of the array, but it is simpler to add a `count` member in `SRC` for this information. It would also be much simpler to make this a pointer to an allocated array of `SRC` objects.

The function does not construct a tree, but attempts to construct a list of directories. Whenever to recurse into a directory, you should append the new list from the `SRC_ERROR` object returned by `scan_source` to the list already constructed in the `SRC_ERROR` object allocated by the caller and free the object returned by the recursive call.

Here is a modified version in a test program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>

#ifndef PATH_MAX
#define PATH_MAX 1024
#endif
#define MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH  16

#define TRACE(x)  //x

enum { OK = 0, ERROR, OUT_OF_MEMORY };

typedef struct ERROR_STATE ERROR_STATE;
struct ERROR_STATE {
    int code;
    const char *message;  // always a string literal
};

typedef struct SRC_FILE SRC_FILE;
struct SRC_FILE {
    char *name;        // points to allocated memory
    char md5[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
};

typedef struct SRC SRC; //Source file tree with md5 entry char for source verification.
struct SRC {
    char *name;         // points to allocated memory
    char *full_path;    // points to allocated memory
    size_t count;       // number of elements in entries
    SRC_FILE *entries;  // allocated array of count elements
    SRC *next_dir;      // the next SRC
};

static char *basename_dup(const char *full_path) {
    char *p = strrchr(full_path, '/');
    return strdup(p ? p + 1 : full_path);
}

/* construct a SRC describing the directory contents.
 * if there is an error, either return a partially constructed SRC or return NULL
 */
SRC *scan_source(const char *source_path, ERROR_STATE *error) {
    char *full_path = strdup(source_path);
    char *name = basename_dup(source_path);
    SRC *source = calloc(1, sizeof(SRC));   // all members initialized to 0

    if (source == NULL) {
        error->code = ERROR;
        error->message = "Unable to allocate memory.\n";
        free(full_path);
        free(name);
        free(source);
        return NULL;
    }

    error->code = OK;
    source->full_path = full_path;
    source->name = name;

    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;

    if (!(dir = opendir(source_path))) {
        error->code = ERROR;
        error->message = "Unable to open source directory.\n";
        return source;
    }

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        char path[PATH_MAX];
        int len;

        if (!strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(entry->d_name, ".."))
            continue;

        len = snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/%s", source_path, entry->d_name);
        if (len >= (int)sizeof(path)) {
            // the path was truncated.
            // you can report this or ignore it...
            TRACE(printf("[%s] - %s - path too long, ignored\n", entry->d_name, path));
            continue;
        }
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            TRACE(printf("[%s] - %s\n", entry->d_name, path));

            SRC *source1 = scan_source(path, error);
            if (error->code != OK) {
                // either ignore the error or abort?
            }
            if (source1) {
                // append the new directory (and its list of sub-directories)
                SRC **tailp = &source->next_dir;
                while (*tailp) tailp = &(*tailp)->next_dir;
                *tailp = source1;
            }
        } else
        if (entry->d_type == DT_REG) {
            TRACE(printf("[FILE] - %s\n", entry->d_name));
            // add the file to the entries list
            SRC_FILE *entries = realloc(source->entries, sizeof(source->entries[0]) * (source->count + 1));
            if (entries == NULL) {
                // you should return to the caller with a proper error code
                error->code = OUT_OF_MEMORY;
                error->message = "cannot reallocate entries array";
                break;
            }
            source->entries = entries;
            // source->entries[count] must point to an allocated object
            name = strdup(entry->d_name);
            if (name == NULL) {
                error->code = OUT_OF_MEMORY;
                error->message = "cannot allocate entry name";
                break;
            }
            source->entries[source->count].name = name;
            memset(source->entries[source->count].md5, 0, sizeof(source->entries[source->count].md5));
            source->count++;
            //if (md5_sum(full_path, source->entries[source->count].md5)) {
            //    // error computing the MD5 sum...
            //}
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
    return source;
}

void free_source(SRC *source) {
    if (source) {
        free(source->name);
        free(source->full_path);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < source->count; i++) {
            free(source->entries[i].name);
        }
        free(source);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[1]) {
    ERROR_STATE error = { 0, NULL };

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("usage: scansource directory [...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        SRC *source = scan_source(argv[i], &error);
        if (error.code) {
            printf("Error %d: %s\n", error.code, error.message);
        }
        while (source) {
            SRC *cur = source;
            source = source->next_dir;

            printf("{\n"
                   "  name: '%s',\n"
                   "  full_path: '%s',\n"
                   "  count: %zu,\n"
                   "  entries: [\n",
                   cur->name, cur->full_path, cur->count);
            for (size_t j = 0; j < cur->count; j++) {
                printf("    { md5: '");
                for (size_t k = 0; k < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; k++)
                    printf("%02x", cur->entries[j].md5[k]);
                printf("', name: '%s' },\n", cur->entries[j].name);
            }
            printf("  ]\n},\n");
            free_source(cur);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```